How to get the member function that contains a specific varDeclRef through AST?
Example code:
#include <string>

class DBFetcher {
  public:
    void findByName(std::string name) {}
    void findByNameV2(std::string name) {}
}

DBFetcher getFetcher() {
  return FBFetcher();
}

void clientFetch() {
  std::string myName = "abc";
  auto res = getFetcher().findByName(std::move(myName));
  return res;
}


With the matcher, I'm able to match the referenced location of the variable myName inside std::move. However, how do I match or traverse to the findByName function? I want to replace the function findByName with v2, as well as change the variable name myName to newName.
Matcher:
auto matcher = declRefExpr(
            isExpansionInMainFile(),
            to(varDecl(hasInitializer(
                           cxxConstructExpr(hasType(cxxRecordDecl(hasName(
                                                "DBFetcher"))))
                               .bind("constructor")))
                   .bind("var")))
            .bind("varRef"));



The example code has several syntax errors.  Please edit it so it compiles as a complete translation unit (with needed #includes).  2. The match expression does not match myName since myName is not initialized with a DBFetcher, and it does not match anything else in the example code (after fixing syntax errors).  Please fix the matcher so it does what the text of the question says it does.  3. Ideally, please show the matcher working in a call to clang-query so it is clear what it does, that it indeed works as stated, and thus one can easily reproduce the issue at the cmd line.


fixed the format.

Did you try compiling the code in the question?  It still has syntax errors, such as a missing semicolon after the class definition and the typo FBFetcher.  I don't know if that is all of them though.
